# jQuery time display with AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm building a webpage that retrieves data from a server using AJAX. I'm looking to display time in a div (in hours/minutes/seconds, like 10:45:30, with leading zeroes). One of my AJAX calls is run very infrequently; roughly 45 minutes or so between each call. The call in question gets a JSON string with the server's current time (via PHP). I'm able to get this string with the hours, minutes, and seconds separated or as one item.

I've seen a lot of timer functions that use `setInterval` and JS functions to get the current time; these operate client-side/locally. I've also seen functions that will ask for the server's time every minute (which seems much too frequent).

What I would like to do is grab the server's time from the AJAX call (which I can assign to variables; this part I have figured out)., and let a timer function use the variables from that call as a starting point to increment the seconds, minutes, etc.

Here's an idea of what this may look like; first, the AJAX call that gets the time variables.

```
function askTime(){
        $.ajax({
                url: "servertime.php",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    timeHours = (data.timeHours);
                    timeMinutes = (data.timeMinutes);
                    timeSeconds = (data.timeSeconds);
                    timerFunction();

                },
            });
    }
```

And then on the success of that call, run the function that would display the time in a div of a certain id, like `$('#timeDisplay).html(timestring)` .

So, shortly: how can I use jQuery to display time using infrequent AJAX calls to server time?

Comment: try a sample code here http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/servertime.shtml may be it will helpful for you

Comment: not sure exactly what you're asking...

Comment: You could use the AJAX call to get the server time, calculate the offset between the result and the client side time and thereon use that offset and the client side time to display your time. Barring any problems with the client side and any daylight savings adjustments you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ticking clock that starts at the time returned, My suggestion would be to load in your time values as numbers, And write loop with a delay in it. `jQuery` has a `.delay()` method that takes a value in milliseconds. So something like

```
function myTimer(hours, minutes, seconds)
{
   while(true)
   {
     //add one to seconds, if equal to 60, set to 0 and add one to minutes,
     //same for hours
     delay(1000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getTime is a web method I set up on the server side that returns the JSON encoded date time (something like /Date(*milliseconds*)/).

You might want to change that part of the javascript (the first line in the success callback) depending on how *you* get your date time from your web service.

```
    var clientTimeUpdater = null;

    function askTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/getTime",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var serverNowGetTime = msg.d.replace(/\/Date\(/, '').replace(/\)\//, '');
                var offset = (new Date()).getTime() - serverNowGetTime;
                clearInterval(clientTimeUpdater)

                // the client side updater
                clientTimeUpdater = setInterval(function () {
                    var serverNowGetTime = new Date((new Date()) - offset);
                    var hh = ('0' + serverNowGetTime.getHours()).slice(-2);
                    var mm = ('0' + serverNowGetTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
                    var ss = ('0' + serverNowGetTime.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
                    $("#myTime").text(hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // first call
        askTime();
        // call every 45 minutes
        setInterval(askTime, 2700000);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are hoping to achieve.

You could use `setInterval()` to update the time every second (or so). Periodically (say every minute) the time would be synchronized with the server via an ajax call. The ajax `success` handler would use `setTimeout` to make the next ajax request.

```
var SYNC_INTERVAL = 60000;
var UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;

var $time = $('#time');

var serverOffset = 0;

function zeroPad(value) {
    return ('0' + value).slice(-2);
}

function updateTime() {
    var date = new Date(Date.now() + serverOffset);
    $time.text(zeroPad(date.getHours())
               + ':' + zeroPad(date.getMinutes())
               + ':' + zeroPad(date.getSeconds()));
}

function requestSyncWithServer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'servertime.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(date) {
            serverOffset = date - Date.now();
            updateTime();
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestSyncWithServer();
            }, SYNC_INTERVAL);
        }
    });
}

updateTime();
setInterval(function() { updateTime(); }, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
requestSyncWithServer();
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g1cv23da/1/)

Comment: @avghighschoolstudent - Are you asking about the format of the `date` value returned by the ajax call? The code in my answer assumes it is a single number representing the milliseconds since the epoch (i.e., Jan 1, 1970). That is a standard way to represent a datetime value. But if your server returns something else, it can easily be accommodated. Just let me know what your server returns and I can help with that.

Comment: @avghighschoolstudent - BTW, I see I forgot to include `dataType: 'json'`. I have added it now.

Comment: I'm using PHP so I can format it easily in a variety of ways. Just needed to know what format you were assuming, although the time is going to be a part of a larger JSON set (so it would be data.TimeStamp for example)